# Symfony2 DOMCrawler - How to select second option of a select tag

Tags: forms, unit-testing, symfony

I'm trying to select the second option in a `<select>` tag with the DOMCcrawler. First of all, I select the second form in the page:

```
$form = $DOMCrawler->filter('form')->eq(1)->filter('input[type=submit]')->form();
```

Then I could change each value of the form by:

```
$form['value'] = "new value";
```

but I don't have a fixed key for each value. Instead, I have a variable number. E.g. I could have something like:

```
$form[1234];
```

but also could be

```
$form[4321];
```

depending on other variables. So I need to change the form values without knowing the key values, but its position in the node `<form>`. E.g. something like `$form->firstKey();`

Also, I want to select the second option inside `<select>` tag, not a fixed value. Any ideas on how to achieve it?